# How do I use org.scribe.oauth to connect to the tumblr API?

Tags: java, api, oauth, tumblr, scribe

I've followed the tutorial given on the [org.scribe page](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/Getting-Started) but it appears that out-of-band callbacks aren't supported. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to solve this? Moreover, a more comprehensive tutorial or documentation for the org.scribe library would be helpful.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Out-of-band ("oob") callbacks are not supported by this implementation.'
at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:63)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:39)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:44)
at com.jruehl.tumbleweed.oauth.AuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthentication(AuthenticationHandler.java:30)
at com.jruehl.tumbleweed.TumbleWeed.main(TumbleWeed.java:30)
```

How do I authenticate? I've attempted to open a webpage for the user to copy/paste the PIN into the application, but this evidently doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 4):

Did you provide a callback url? I added the url `http://localhost:8080/` even I'm developing a desktop application and it worked.